# creating weekly scheme for id's part 1

Tags: sql, sas

I have data as follows and would like to eventually aggregate the the data on a weekly basis. The first step is to create the weeks for customers.

```
data have;
input ID  start  :mmddyy10. channel  type $;
datalines;
1  05/21/2009  143  radio
1  05/30/2009  157  television
2  01/01/2011  45  television
2  01/09/2011  53  computerRadio
;;;;
run;
```

I want each ID to have their own first week so that the data looks like this

```
data want;
input ID  start  :mmddyy10. channel  type $ week;
datalines;
1  05/21/2009  143  radio 1
1  05/30/2009  157  television 2
2  01/01/2011  45  television 1
2  01/09/2011  53  computerRadio 2
;;;;
run;
```

doing this in SAS, so proc sql is an option, and a much preferred one.  Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you looked into so far?

Comment: cleaned the data and spent a long time reading SAS documentation about dates.

Comment: You need to do one of two things, to avoid this question looking like a "please write my program for me", in particular with the "part 1": either ask a much more specific question ("How do I do X" is not very specific, "How do I use Y and Z methods to accomplish X" is) or try to solve it explicitly yourself and post that code, with your question being about what you aren't getting right.

Comment: documentation only tells me how to start weeks from specific time on the calendar, but I need every ID to have their own week 1 and then count the next six days as the rest of week 1, and then week 2...i counldnt edit the title

Comment: Then perhaps post how you have figured out so far (how to do it from one specific time), and we can guide you into customizing that for <each user>.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.

```
proc sort data=have;
   by id start;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   by id start;
   retain week;
   if first.id then week = 1;
   else week = week + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, which is not one record per week necessarily.